# WebView Scroll Issue

Tags: cocoa

I am using web-view in my application and showing a message content in HTML format
When I try  to forward a long message I am setting the web view editable.
In this case the scroll of web-view is not working properly

means.. when I am pressing Enter after first 2-3 lines then those lines go upward from viewing before I reach the bottom of the page.

My forwarded message is in the 1st Photo of link
http://picasaweb.google.com/battan20/Error#

When I press some Enter after a few lines then first line goes slightly upward after pressing a few enter. as in 2nd Photo
When I press some more Enter after the line then first line goes slightly upward, as in 3nd Photo.... as so on

As per normal scroll work first line should not goes upper until my cursor not reach in the end of page

Thanks
Amit Battan

Answer (score 0):

Can we get the cursor position and scrollview height in Webview.

so that I use the delegate methods to set the scroll position manually delegate method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(WebView *)webView shouldInsertText:(NSString *)text replacingDOMRange:(DOMRange *)range givenAction:(WebViewInsertAction)action
```